# Entity Framework Core POST error (JSON value could not be converted)

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have the following entities:

```
public class Order 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public OrderGroup OrderGroup { get; set; }
}

public class OrderGroup 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

When I make a `POST` request for an `Order`, I get an error in Swagger:

> The Order field is required
>
> The JSON value could not be converted to <API.Entities.Order> . Path: $.OrderGroup.order |

Which makes sense because I am able to fix the error if I change to null in my payload (`OrderGroup.order`). But I need it so an `Order` can optionally have an `OrderGroup` (so I should be able to create an `Order` without `OrderGroup`).

What would be the best way to approach this?

Are there annotations to handle this or would I do this client side. I say annotations since I haven't used modelBuilder yet.

This is a one-to-one relationship.

I tried:

- Changed to null on the payload works but need to handle this properly
- Also added `?` to `OrderGroup`, and `Order` still throws the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest advice to avoid issues like this is to avoid sending entities between the server and client.

For a POST to create an order, define something like a CreateOrderViewModel:

```
[Serializable]
public class CreateOrderViewModel
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int? OrderGroupId { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task CreateOrder(CreateOrderViewModel viewModel)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(viewModel, nameof(viewModel));

    OrderGroup? orderGroup = viewModel.OrderGroupId.HasValue 
        ? _context.OrderGroups.Single(x => x.Id == viewModel.OrderGroupId)
        : null;

    var newOrder = new Order
    { 
        Name = viewModel.Name,
        OrderGroup = orderGroup
    };
    _context.Orders.Add(newOrder);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

This assumes that an order may, or may not belong to an OrderGroup. This isn't a one-to-one relationship, rather a many-to-one relationship. Many orders might associate with an order group. the Order table would contain an OrderGroupId. By making the OrderGroupId null-able, the order is not required to have an OrderGroup association.  One-to-one relationships typically share the same PK, though EF can enforce a one-to-one with a separate FK like a many-to-one with a unique constraint.

Passing entities poses a number of problems with association vs. creation as the entities will all be detached and the context can end up with existing references causing errors.  When populated and sent from a view to a controller they may "look" like entities, but they are just values copied into instances of an entity class. They may not be complete, and if you use something like `Update` with them, you can be overwriting data with untrustworthy values. Entities are also a heavyweight class to be sending with issues like circular references, plus generally including more data than is really needed to get the job done.

Comment: Fixed all my problems using DTOs but have two questions:

1) Is it best to create another DTO for POST Requests? So now I have two DTOs one for GET and one for POST. Or should I do this in my Controller method.

2) Foreign keys are defaulting to 0. I need foreign keys (e.g. Order doesn't need an OrderGroup) as optional so should be null if they don't enter anything. I added an if statement to my controller to check if it equals 0 and convert it to null. But is this the best way to go about it?

Comment: If you are using a FormPost typically the Get ViewModel is what gets submitted in the Post. If you are taking more of an Ajax approach with non-submit posts then you can create a dedicated DTO or a partially/wholly filled Get VM. Posts are just parameterized values so your controller method could just have named parameters vs. a DTO vs. an entity and it'd work fine. The problem with using an entity as the container is that what is sent from the view is rarely complete (and overkill if you do make it complete) and should not be trusted to be attached and updated as an entity.

Comment: Cheers, tested both options. Having a separate DTO is more clean but at the same time a bit more maintenace considering GET and POST are the same apart from one navigation property which doesn’t need to be in the Post. 2nd option of one DTO then not filling it in during the request still has it appearing in Swagger although I could just avoid that object. Of course user perspective both work!